# It would protect those who were vaccinated from getting sick

Tags: grammar

> For a vaccine to get from phase I to phase III trials in just ten months, as rVSV-ZEBOV did, was unheard of at the time—a startling example of what urgency and organisation can do. Now a repeat performance, ideally taken at an even faster tempo, is the sum of the world’s desire. In the middle of April more people are dying of covid-19 every three days than died of Ebola in west Africa over three years. A vaccine would not just save lives; it would change the course of the pandemic in two separate, **if related**, ways. **It would protect those who were vaccinated from getting sick**; and by reducing the number of susceptible people it would prevent the virus from spreading, thus also protecting the unvaccinated.

I have 2 questions

- what does "if related" mean and why is separated by comma?
- would ... were, is it subjunctive? If not, will the meaning be different if I change it to simple present tense as "It would protect those who ARE vaccinated from getting sick"?

article link : https://www.economist.com/briefing/2020/04/16/can-the-world-find-a-good-covid-19-vaccine-quickly-enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"if related"* qualifies the previous *"two separate"*. It says that they are not *"two completely separate"* things but they have overlapping effects. The next sentence list the two things, separated by the semi-colon.

---

I am less sure on the second question, but my thought are:

The suggested words *"It would protect those who ARE vaccinated from getting sick"* feels wrong (to my UK senses). To me the suggested words have an implicit *"already"* as in *are already vaccinated"*.

The words *" It would protect those who were vaccinated from getting sick"* mean that vaccinating a person protects them from getting sick. The *"were vaccinated"* is the act of giving the vaccine, the rest of the words are about the benefits of having been given the vaccine.